# Merged feature into master, reverted, then merging master into feature causes problems

Tags: git, github, merge

I am in a unique Git merging situation.

I cut off a `feature` branch from a `master` branch. I made some changes on `feature`, while other people kept committing to `master`. Then, I merged  `feature` into `master`. Immediately after, I had to revert this merge commit, restoring `master` to it's pre-merge state.

I continued developing on `feature`. After some time, to bring `feature`  up-to-date with `master`, I tried to merge `master` into `feature`. After the merge, my resultant `feature` branch is missing most files that were present only in `feature`, and not in `master`. It also overwrote the  files that were common in between both branches with their `master` versions, without reporting any merge conflicts. The reason for this is the fact that (as mentioned in the first paragraph) I had previously tried to merge `feature` into master, and then immediately reverted that merge. This makes Git think that the files from `feature` were present in `master` at some point in it's history, then deleted from `master` due to some reason, and hence it tries to delete those files from the resultant `feature` branch after `master` is merged into it.

So, as of now, I have my `feature` branch with `master` merged into it, but it contains almost no files that were only in the `feature` branch. Thankfully, I have a local copy of my pre-merge `feature` branch, so I can see which files are missing after the merge, and then add them manually. I am also having to find conflicts manually this way, instead of Git reporting them.

This is a lot of manual work. Is there an easy way to get out of this situation? I would like to have the ability to do a 'proper' merge of `master` into my backup copy of pre-merge `feature`.

Answer (score 0):

An error is in your `master`. If you have a privilege to force push `master`,try to hard reset instead of revert:

```
$ git reset --hard commit-id
```

That will discard your revert commit and merge commit ,then you can merge `master` into `feature`

If there are some correct commits after that 2 wrong commit, use `rabase` to discard that 2 commit.

Be careful , force push may ruin your repo if you make some mistakes.

---

If you have no privilege of `master`, revert the revert commit again, if you can't do that.Maybe just checkout the newest file from `master`  into `feature` directly instead of merge them will be better.